# How to make sql query more dynamic in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, gridview

I have a webpage and a gridview connected to a database table. My update queries of the columns are as followed:

```
if (oldName != NAME && oldCreated == DATE)
{
    GeneralDbExecuterService.executeSqlNonQuery(string.Format("UPDATE EXCEPTIONAL_USE_POLICY_PARAM SET NAME  = '{0}' WHERE ID = '{1}' ", NAME, ID));
}

// if date was changed alone
if (oldCreated != DATE && oldName == NAME)
{
    GeneralDbExecuterService.executeSqlNonQuery(string.Format("UPDATE EXCEPTIONAL_USE_POLICY_PARAM SET CREATED_DATE = to_date('{0}', 'dd/MM/yyyy') WHERE ID = '{1}' ", DATE, ID));
}

// if both values were changed
if (oldName != NAME && oldCreated != DATE)
{
    GeneralDbExecuterService.executeSqlNonQuery(string.Format("UPDATE EXCEPTIONAL_USE_POLICY_PARAM SET NAME  = '{0}', CREATED_DATE = to_date('{2}', 'dd/MM/yyyy') WHERE ID = '{1}' ", NAME, ID, DATE));
}
```

My question is, how can I make it more modular?

For example if 2 more columns are added its going to raise my IFs by few if not dozens. What is the best way to achieve that kind of dynamic approach? And is that even possible?. Thanks

edit: my main goal is to be able to detect what/where change has happened, and query the specific columns/values . ( basically its what I did) im just asking if theres a better way because if I were to add 5 more columns, I'd end up adding 40 more if statements..

Answer (score 0):

If you use Entity Framework, rather than raw SQL, then you won't need to have any `if` statements at all. Your method would take an entity, and your code would just get the existing entity out of the database, and set the properties from the incoming one, irrespective of whether or not they have changed (air code, assumptions made about how you set up your model, etc)...

```cs
private async Task Update(PolicyParam p) {
  PolicyParam existing = await dbContext.PolicyParams.Single(pp => pp.Id == p.Id);
  existing.Date = p.Date;
  existing.Name = p.Name;
  // Update other properties here
  await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

If you add another column, you just add one more line of code above.

EF has a zillion other benefits, like cleaner code, less chance of SQL injection, etc.